# SQL Query - Contains query not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, contains

I have a column in my MySQL called 'country' What I want to be able to do is to load multiple records if the country column contains the country code that my visitor have.

Lets say there are 2 offers for the same country. (US, GB)

So the column, 'country' would look like this: US,GB

```
Country | Name | Description

US,GB   | ...  | ....
```

Then it should be able to check if the 'country' column contains the country code, which is either US or GB. And then load the offer available for that country.

So far I have this MySQL query, but it is not working.

```
mysql_query("SELECT popularity, name, description, category, enabled FROM list WHERE country LIKE '$country_code' AND enabled='0'");
```

I hope you understand, what I am trying to say. Thanks for any response!

Comment: This isn't proper database design, but update your LIKE statement with the wildcard - `WHERE country LIKE '%".$country_code."%'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the wildcard `%` which is a substitute for zero or more characters.

```
mysql_query("SELECT popularity, name, description, category, enabled FROM list WHERE country LIKE '%$country_code%' AND enabled='0'");
```

Answer (score 1):

### Never, never, never store multiple values in one column.

You should only store 1 country at a time like this

```
Country | Name | Description
US      | ...  | ....
GB      | ...  | ....
```

If you can't change the DB design then you can run

```
SELECT popularity, name, description, category, enabled 
FROM list 
WHERE enabled='0'
AND find_in_set('$country_code', country) > 0
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem is with the ID. When I try to add an offer that have already been added and are for two or more countries I cannot do it because the ID is unique. And it would be a lot more simple if there could be 2 country codes in the 'country' column. But can you explain why I shouldent store multiple values in one column? Thanks!

Comment: You should not because it is way faster, cleaner and easier to select a single value from a column! And it is the first rule or DB normalization.

Comment: Okay, but it's only about 4-5 offers. I understand that it is bad for big datasets, and looks unprofessional. But for now this will have to do. Thank you!

Comment: *For now*. Yeah - that's how it starts **always**. ;)